# Вместо формы обратной связи Contact Form 7 выводится шорткод

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form7

Сайт на Вордпрессе на котором реализована всплывающая форма обратной связи с помощью плагинов Easy FancyBox и Contact Form 7. На главной странице сайта форма работает нормально, но ни как не получается прикрутить её к категории товаров WooCommerce, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку у товара "Узнать цену" всплывала форма обратной связи.

Добавил код в файл functions.php темы (пробовал вт нескольких темах):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'custom_product_link' );
function custom_product_link( $link ) {
global $product;
    echo '<div class="contact-us2"><a href="#contact_form_pop_up" class="fancybox-inline">Узнать цену</a></div>
<div style="display:none" class="fancybox-hidden">
<div id="contact_form_pop_up">
[contact-form-7 id="13297" title="Узнать цену"]
</div>
</div>';
}
```

В результате окно появляется, но вместо формы показывается просто шорткод
`[contact-form-7 id="13297" title="Узнать цену"]`
[image]

Подскажите как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 3):

Html с шорткодом надо выводить через do_shortcode()

```
echo do_shortcode( '<div class="contact-us2"><a href="#contact_form_pop_up" class="fancybox-inline">Узнать цену</a></div> <div style="display:none" class="fancybox-hidden"> <div id="contact_form_pop_up"> [contact-form-7 id="13297" title="Узнать цену"] </div> </div>' );
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! Помогло :)

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.